# Always get permission denied on tar. cannot mkdir: permission denied on my kafka installation

Tags: apache-kafka, tar

so i just downloaded kafka in binary files (.tgz) and i put that file into my directory /mnt/c:/Program Files/Kafka/

but when i want to un-tar that file with this code

```
tar -xvf kafka_2.13-2.8.0\ \(1\).tgz
```

or even with `sudo`

but i always get notification error

`tar: kafka_2.13-2.8.0: Cannot Mkdir: Permission Denied`

where my wrong at?

updated :
based on @Jagadesh request, here's the result of `ls -al`

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWmQC.png)

i tried with @Jagadesh advice, so i run this :

```
chmod 755 /mnt/c/"Program Files (x86)"/"Kafka"
```

but it produce same thing like this :

```
chmod: changing permissions of '/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Kafka' : permission denied
```

Comment: Not having sufficient permission to create directory, execute `chmod 755 <path>` to the directory where the tar is placed.. or else switch to the user which has the permission.. Can you execute `ls -al` and post it here, so that can analyze much deeper and help

Comment: wait, let me update with ```ls-al``` result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, After do research, i change the permission on my windows into my users settings to full control, i do this with right click and setting on security based on this article https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/take-ownership-folder-windows-10-using-file-explorer

Comment: You shouldn't be installing WSL Linux packages under Windows program files anyway. Plus, Kafka prefers to have no spaces in its installation directory

Comment: can you give me more example on no spaces in its installation directory?

Comment: "Program Files (x86)" has spaces. `/opt/kafka` within WSL or C:\kafka in Windows do not